Add clickable link while adding comments to vscode
I wanted to refer to links while writing comments for the code. It could be anything like images or a URL that explains a concept.
For eg: /**
*../../../Array/loops/2024-07-07-17-02-11.png
*/
I should be able to click this location and able to open the image directly.
I have been finding ways to do this, but could not find anything on my own. How to add a clickable link to comments in vscode?

You can use left ctrl + left mouse click to open a link in vscode.

editor URL detection should do this automatically for URL patterns...

Can you expand @starball?

Try JSDoc comment or any inline comment starting with /** and ends with */. For instance:
/**
 * For clickable link {@link https://example.com/}
 */


/* https://example.com crtl&click the link!*/.

